How to prove selectively-secure scheme is adaptively secure when message space is small?
I'm reading this paper From Selective to Adaptive Security in Functional Encryption. The author said that if message space is not too large, then any adaptively-chosen message $x$ can be guessed ahead of time with probability $2^{−n}$, then it is possible to prove that selectively-secure scheme is also adaptively secure.

But how to covert this intuition into a proof?

The proof employs a guessing strategy, as mentioned in the snippet provided in the question. Our goal is to demonstrate that a functional encryption (FE) scheme with selective security for a small message space $\{0,1\}^n$ is also adaptively secure, except with a slight reduction in security. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an adversary that successfully breaks the adaptive security of the FE scheme. We will construct an adversary $\mathcal{B}$ that achieves success in the selective security game with nearly the same probability as $\mathcal{A}$.
In the selective security game, the adversary begins by choosing two messages. Here, $\mathcal{B}$ selects two random messages $m_0, m_1$, sends them to its challenger and receives the master public key $mpk$ and the challenge ciphertext $CT \gets FE.Enc(mpk, m_b)$ for a random bit $b$. Next, it forwards $mpk$ to $\mathcal{A}$ and handles queries from $\mathcal{A}$ by relaying them to its challenger. In the challenge phase, $\mathcal{A}$ will send two message $m_0', m_1'$ to $\mathcal{B}$. If $m_0 \neq m_0'$ or $m_1 \neq m_1'$, then $\mathcal{B}$ outputs a random bit $b''$. Otherwise, it provides $CT$ to $\mathcal{A}$. The simulation continues until $\mathcal{A}$ outputs a guess $b'$, which $\mathcal{B}$ then outputs as its own answer.
Observe that the probability that $\mathcal{B}$ does not output $b''$ and completes the entire simulation is $\frac{1}{2^{2n}}$. Therefore, we have
$$
\begin{align*}
Pr[\mathcal{B} \text{ wins the selective game}] &= \left(1- \dfrac{1}{2^{2n}} \right)\dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{Pr[\mathcal{A} \text{ wins the adaptive game}]}{2^{2n}}\\
&= \dfrac{1}{2} + \underbrace{\left(Pr[\mathcal{A} \text{ wins the adaptive game}] - \dfrac{1}{2}\right)}_{\text{Advantage of }\mathcal{A}} \dfrac{1}{2^{2n}}
\end{align*}
$$
It is important to note that $\mathcal{B}$ wins with significant probability only if the advantage of $\mathcal{A}$ is non-negligible and $n$ is small.

Is the function $2^{-n}$ non-negligible in this case? The definition of negligible function seems to be independent of the actual input range.

Yes. I believe the authors intended $n$ to be a small constant, or at least chosen so that $2^{-n}$ is non-negligible in the security parameter. This is why they say "message space is not too large".

But the authors choose the security parameter here to be polynomial in n(refer to line 8 in the image). Is there a problem with this choice?

My mistake. If we are assuming sub-exponential hardness, then there is more freedom to choose $n$. The definition is not precise but sub-exponential hardness means that no adversary $\mathcal{B}$ can win with probability $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^{\lambda^{\delta}}}$ for some $\delta > 0$. In this case, we can let $n = \lambda^{1/c}$ for some constant $c$.
